# PHP: get array element

Tags: php, arrays

Why does this code not work?

```
echo explode("?", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])[0];
```

It says `syntax error, unexpected '['`.

Oddly, this works:

```
$tmp = explode("?", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
echo $tmp[0];
```

But I really want to avoid to create such a `$tmp` variable here.

How do I fix it?

---

After the helpful answers, some remaining questions: Is there any good reason of the design of the language to make this not possible? Or did the PHP implementors just not thought about this? Or was it for some reason difficult to make this possible?

Comment: See http://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing

Comment: [Array Dereferencing will come to a PHP near you soon](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a (silly) limitation of the current PHP parser that your first example doesn't work. However, supposedly the next major version of PHP will fix this.

Answer (score 5):

Unlike Javascript, PHP can't address an array element after a function. You have to split it up into two statements or use array_slice().

Comment: Yea that seems so. :) But why? Is there any good reason of the design of the language? Or did the PHP implementors just not thought about this? Or was it for some reason difficult to make this possible?

Comment: You can use current() and next() functions for 0 and 1 elements too.

Comment: Or use `list` on the left hand side.

Answer (score 4):

This is only allowed in the development branch of PHP (it's a new feature called "array dereferencing"):

```
echo explode("?", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])[0];
```

You can do this

```
list($noQs) = explode("?", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

or use  [`array_slice`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484832/php-get-array-element/3484859#3484859)/temp variable, like [stillstanding](https://stackoverflow.com/users/336508/stillstanding) said. You shouldn't use `array_shift`, as it expects an argument passed by reference.

Comment: -1 He don't want to use extra variable(temp) and want to access it directly. What is the difference between $noQs(in your anwser) and $temp(in his question) here.

Answer (score 2):

[Take a look at this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470227/php-url-question/3470384#3470384).

Hoohaah's suggestion of using strstr() is quite nice. The following will return from the beginning of the string until the first `?` (the third argument for strstr() is only available for PHP 5.3.0 onward):

```
echo strstr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "?", TRUE);
```

Or if you want to stick with explode, you can make use if [list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php). (The 2 indicates that at most 2 elements will be returned by explode).

```
list($url) = explode("?", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 2);
echo $url;
```

Finally, to use the natively available [PHP URL parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php);

```
$info = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
echo $info["scheme"] . "://" . $info["host"] . $info["path"];
```

Comment: He's trying to remove it, not recover it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Although, the only thing I want is to get just everything before the first `?`, so I guess `explode` is just easier here, isn't it?

Comment: @Albert: In that case, just use `strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'?',TRUE)`

Comment: @hoohah - That's a great idea (for PHP 5.3.0 onward).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

```
echo current(explode("?",  $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));
```

Comment: array_shift should be passed an argument by reference.

Comment: I did not understand the problem. Can you explain in detail? For example I have a current URL `http://test.dev/index.php?input=10`. When I use `echo current( explode("?",  $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) );` then the output is `/index.php`. What is the problem here and what exactly result is required ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe PHP 5.4 comes with this feature, at long last. Sadly, it will be a while before your average web host updates their PHP version. My Ubuntu VPS doesn't even have it in the default repos.