# Get a value of returned array

Tags: php

How can I write this code in one php operator?

```
$menu = theme('nice_menu', 1, 10, 'down');
print $menu['content'];
```

Something like this:

```
print theme('nice_menu', 1, 10, 'down')['content'];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: get array element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484832/php-get-array-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not on a production version of PHP.  This has been added to the trunk for the next version (Currently called 5.3.99DEV, but it's unsure if it'll be 5.4 or 6.0 or what)...  It's called Array Dereferencing.  See the [RFP](http://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing)...

Answer (score 0):

This is, unfortunately, not possible (at the current state of PHP). Your first example is the way to do it.